# JQuery Autocomplete. If item cannot be found, display "Press Enter to insert into autocomplete"?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am doing kind of a tag-autocomplete combo.

So basically when user enters a query that has no autocomplete options, i.e "aaa", I want autocomplete to drop down and display "Press 'Enter' to create a tag for 'aaa'. "

I can't find anything on the docs (I suppose this requires me to do some hacking, but before doing so, I wanna see if anyone has done a patch for this.)

EDIT:

I have began working on the source code and this is what I have:

```
 $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response= function( content ) {
    /* BUG: when the user clicks "Press Enter to this tag", 
     *  the tag "Press enter to create this tag" 
     *  gets created
     */
    console.log(content);
    if (content.length == 0) { 
      content = [{ 'label': "Press Enter to create this tag.", "value": -1 }];
    }

    if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length ) {
      content = this._normalize( content );
      this._suggest( content );
      this._trigger( "open" );
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
    this.pending--;
    if ( !this.pending ) {
      this.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
    }
  };
```

This works fine. However, when the when the user clicks "Press Enter to this tag", the tag "Press enter to create this tag" gets created. How do I fix this to the original query?

Comment: Do your users really care whether the tag exists or not? For most cases I'd say the do not. Generally it seems more user friendly to make creation of new tags transparent to a user. I assume your autocomplete list will add a tag when its selected from a the results, but you can still have an "Add Tag" button or something similar even if it's not in use when a tag is found. Then if no result is found or the user doesn't want to click an autocomplete option they can still add a tag. by clicking the submit (or hitting enter). Just a thought.

Comment: @Jeremy I think the cleanest way would be just to tell the user to type and enter. If user types something that exists, it will show, however, if the query is not found, an empty box might confuse user. I just want to show "Press 'Enter' to create this tag" within the autocomplete search box

Comment: My point was only that if there is a submit button it will appear as just an input with a submit to a user which I don't think is confusing. But that's just my opinion, I haven't done focus groups to back that up! :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is partially derived from the requester's logic. I'm posting my solution here, hopefully it helps someone. Basically we make a request for a term and if that term doesn't exist we'll allow the user to click on a fake result (click here to add). Upon doing so they trigger a request to add the term. After that happens we clear the autocomplete to it's initial status and append the newly created term to a div that lists the selected terms. I also store the id's to be saved after the user completes the form.

```
  $("#local-sponsor").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: applications.Urls.FindLocalSponsor,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    alreadyselected: function () {
                        var ids = [];
                        $("#localsponsor-div div.tagButton").each(function () {
                            ids.push($(this).data("id"));
                        });
                        return ids;
                    }
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length === 0) {
                        data = [{ 'label': "Click here to create", "value": request.term, "id": -1 }];
                    }
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.id === -1) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: applications.Urls.AddLocalSponsor,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        term: ui.item.value
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.id !== 0) {
                            var upto = parseInt($("#upto-localsponsor").val());
                            var e = '<div class="tagButton" data-id="' + data.id + '">' + data.value + '<a class="remove remove-researcher-co"></a><input type="hidden" name="LocalSponsors[' + upto + ']" id="LocalSponsors' + upto + '_" value="' + data.id + '"/></div>';
                            $("#localsponsor-div").append(e);
                            $("#upto-localsponsor").val(upto + 1);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(this).val(''); return false;
            } else {
                var upto = parseInt($("#upto-localsponsor").val());
                var e = '<div class="tagButton" data-id="' + ui.item.id + '">' + ui.item.label + '<a class="remove remove-researcher-co"></a><input type="hidden" name="LocalSponsors[' + upto + ']" id="LocalSponsors' + upto + '_" value="' + ui.item.id + '"/></div>';
                $("#localsponsor-div").append(e);
                $("#upto-localsponsor").val(upto + 1);
                $(this).val(''); return false;
            }
        },
        response: function(event, ui) {
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get you're autocomplete results, but if for example you're getting it in a $.getJSON() call, and filling the combo's items based on the result (and not just giving the result of the call straight to the control) you could check whether the result.length == 0, and if so, add something else (like an element saying "Press Enter to create") to the combo.

Please show some code, if you want more precise answer!

Comment: I am using tag-it, and it's passing in via https://github.com/levycarneiro/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js

which method should I overwrite?

Comment: Where is it getting its list from? (What to choose the possible completed items from?)

Comment: It gets via tag_input.autocomplete({ source: options.availableTags }) where options.availableTags is a json list: [ {value:1, label:tag1}, {value2: label:tag2}, ... ]